# Reactjs problems with radio buttons when fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, fetch-api, radio-group

I want to build menu for my website with food cards. I fetch data(name of food, recipe, price) from my rest api and then i show this data on my react app. In this food card I have three radio buttons for mini, middle and maxi prices. When I change button on one card it changes on all cards. [First image, when price 35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guks5.png) and

[Second image, when I change price on first card, but it changes on all cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zso7.png)

this is my code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        shavermas : [],
        price : ''
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.findAllPosts();
}

findAllPosts(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/shaverma/all")
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({shavermas: data})
        });
}

onChange = e =>{
    this.setState({price : e.target.value})
}

 render(){
let {price} = this.state;
const {shavermas} = this.state;
return(
  <>
      {shavermas.map((shaverma, index) => (
    <div className="food-cart">
        <div className="product-img-div">
        <img
            src={shavermaPhoto}
            className="d-inline-block product-img"
            alt="shaverma"
          /> 
        </div>
        <div className="food-cart-body">
            <div>
            <h3>Шаверма <span>{shaverma.foodName}</span></h3>
            <p>{shaverma.recipe}</p>
                <form className="radio-buttons">
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMini} onChange={this.onChange} checked={price.charAt(0) == '' ? shaverma.priceMini : price == shaverma.priceMini}/>
                            <span>Mini</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMiddle} onChange={this.onChange} checked={price == shaverma.priceMiddle}/>
                            <span>Middle</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMaxi} onChange={this.onChange} checked={price == shaverma.priceMaxi} />
                            <span>Maxi</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className="food-cart-footer">
                    <strong>{price.charAt(0) === '' ? shaverma.priceMini : price}₴</strong>
                    <p>Хочу!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      ))}
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Could you supply a working example in sites like Code Sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
You are using common Price state for all cards, you have to use price property for individual card,
Use it like this : 

    onChange = (e,index) =>{
    let newShavermas = this.state.shavermas ;
    newShavermas[index].price=e.target.value;
    this.setState({price : e.target.value})
}
and while fetching the result include price property in each record
    findAllPosts(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/shaverma/all")
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) => {
            let dataVal = data.map(ele=>ele.Price='');
            this.setState({shavermas: dataVal })
        });
}


and in return call onChange like this :

    return(
  <>
      {shavermas.map((shaverma, index) => (
    <div className="food-cart">
        <div className="product-img-div">
        <img
            src={shavermaPhoto}
            className="d-inline-block product-img"
            alt="shaverma"
          /> 
        </div>
        <div className="food-cart-body">
            <div>
            <h3>Шаверма <span>{shaverma.foodName}</span></h3>
            <p>{shaverma.recipe}</p>
                <form className="radio-buttons">
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMini} onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e,index)}  checked={shaverma.price.charAt(0) == '' ? shaverma.priceMini : price == shaverma.priceMini}/>
                            <span>Mini</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMiddle} onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e,index)}  checked={shaverma.price == shaverma.priceMiddle}/>
                            <span>Middle</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="radio">
                        <label className="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" value={shaverma.priceMaxi} onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e,index)}  checked={shaverma.price == shaverma.priceMaxi} />
                            <span>Maxi</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className="food-cart-footer">
                    <strong>{shaverma.price.charAt(0) === '' ? shaverma.priceMini : shaverma.price}₴</strong>
                    <p>Хочу!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      ))}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Tried to fix the tab error to move the text out of the code block, seems to be reverted

Answer (score 0):

This is because all of you cart items are looking at the same state value!

```
onChange = e =>{
   this.setState({price : e.target.value}) < --- changes price to all cards
}
```

To solve this, you will need to have a `price` inside each `shaverma` then change it alone.

I would suggest starting by creating a `FootCart` component with its own state.

Something along the line of:

```
class FootCart implements React.Component {
   ...
   render() {
     return (
      <div className="food-cart">
      ...
      </div>
  }
}

class Cards implements React.Component {
   ...

   render(){
     return (
       <>
        {shavermas.map((shaverma, index) => (<FootCart props/>)}
       </>
     }
}
```

Good Luck!